# How to serialize a JSON into a C# class without a name

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following JSON data received from the Toggl API:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1234567,
    "name": "My Workspace",
    "profile": 100,
    "premium": true,
    "admin": true,
    "default_hourly_rate": 1000,
    "default_currency": "USD",
    "only_admins_may_create_projects": true,
    "only_admins_see_billable_rates": true,
    "only_admins_see_team_dashboard": true,
    "projects_billable_by_default": true,
    "rounding": 0,
    "rounding_minutes": 0,
    "api_token": "some-api-token",
    "at": "2010-10-11T20:09:29+00:00",
    "logo_url": "https://assets.toggl.com/logos/i-am-awesome.png",
    "ical_url": "/ical/workspace_user/mr-awesome",
    "ical_enabled": true,
    "subscription": {
      "workspace_id": 0,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "updated_at": null,
      "vat_valid": false,
      "vat_validated_at": null,
      "vat_invalid_accepted_at": null,
      "vat_invalid_accepted_by": null,
      "description": "Pro monthly",
      "vat_applicable": false
    }
  }
]
```

I used the handy `Paste Special... Paste JSON as Classes` on the Visual Studio 2015 `Edit` menu to get the following class structure:

```
public class TogglWorkspaceTest
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int profile { get; set; }
        public bool premium { get; set; }
        public bool admin { get; set; }
        public int default_hourly_rate { get; set; }
        public string default_currency { get; set; }
        public bool only_admins_may_create_projects { get; set; }
        public bool only_admins_see_billable_rates { get; set; }
        public bool only_admins_see_team_dashboard { get; set; }
        public bool projects_billable_by_default { get; set; }
        public int rounding { get; set; }
        public int rounding_minutes { get; set; }
        public string api_token { get; set; }
        public DateTime at { get; set; }
        public string logo_url { get; set; }
        public string ical_url { get; set; }
        public bool ical_enabled { get; set; }
        public Subscription subscription { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subscription
    {
        public int workspace_id { get; set; }
        public object deleted_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public object updated_at { get; set; }
        public bool vat_valid { get; set; }
        public object vat_validated_at { get; set; }
        public object vat_invalid_accepted_at { get; set; }
        public object vat_invalid_accepted_by { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public bool vat_applicable { get; set; }
    }

}
```

So my question revolves mainly around the `Property1` object in the `Rootobject` class. I cannot seem to get this to map properly and I *think* this is because the JSON serialization is attempting to match up the name `Property1` to a name in the JSON somewhere but there is no name in the JSON at all.

I tried adding `[DataContract]` before every class and `[DataMember]` before every property, but that didn't work. I also tried adding `[DataMember(Name="")]` before the `Property1` declaration, but that didn't work either.

Here is my serialization code for reference:

```
    public static T MakeRequest<T>(string strUrl, string[][] strHeaders, string strRequestMethod = "GET") where T : class
    {
        // NOTE PARAMETERS ARE PASSED IN QUERYSTRING INSIDE URL

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = strRequestMethod;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            foreach (string[] strHeader in strHeaders)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(strHeader[0], strHeader[1]);
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format(
                    "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                    response.StatusCode,
                    response.StatusDescription));
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
                var jsonResponse = (T)objResponse;
                response.Close();
                return jsonResponse;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE*

So what I forgot to share is how I am calling `MakeRequest` from the program...

```
        string[] strAuth = new string[] { "Authorization", $"Basic {strAuthCode}" };

        string[][] myHeaders = new string[][] { strAuth };

        TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1 WorkspaceRequest = MakeRequest<TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1>("https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces", myHeaders);
```

and (thanks to @Plutonix) literally ALL I HAD TO CHANGE, was adding the `[]` after `TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1`

so now I have this and it works perfectly...

```
        string[] strAuth = new string[] { "Authorization", $"Basic {strAuthCode}" };

        string[][] myHeaders = new string[][] { strAuth };

        TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1[] WorkspaceRequest = MakeRequest<TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1[]>("https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces", myHeaders);
```

Thanks again to @Plutonix!

Comment: I am not sure those classes match.  that RootObject seems to have no counterpart in the dta

Comment: Confirmed.  Works fine in JSON.NET except it is an array

Comment: well it looks like the issue is that the toggl api delivers an array of JSON not just the JSON itself. otherwise seems to be working.

Comment: so this might be a strange question, but how can i extract the JSON from the single-member array represented as text?

Comment: Sorry that question makes no sense.  The JSON is the `[  { ... }]` block you posted.  It represents an array of 1 item with a number of property values.  Are you asking how to parse out just one value?

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding, i thought above you were saying that what i'm getting is an ARRAY with JSON inside the array. or are you saying i'm getting JSON that happens to include an array? if the JSON includes an ARRAY, then i am back to step one, meaning how do i represent that array properly in the class since it has no name?

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();`  and `var myCol = jss.Deserialize<Class1[]>(jstr);` will give you an array of Class1 containing some data and a `subscription` property containing more props

Comment: you are fantastic. thank you @Plutonix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @Plutonix deserves the credit, but everything was in the comments, so I'm posting the solution here for others to reference.

What I forgot to share is how I am calling `MakeRequest` from the program...

```
    string[] strAuth = new string[] { "Authorization", $"Basic {strAuthCode}" };

    string[][] myHeaders = new string[][] { strAuth };

    TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1 WorkspaceRequest = MakeRequest<TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1>("https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces", myHeaders);
```

and (thanks to @Plutonix) literally ALL I HAD TO CHANGE, was adding the `[]` after `TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1`

so now I have this and it works perfectly...

```
    string[] strAuth = new string[] { "Authorization", $"Basic {strAuthCode}" };

    string[][] myHeaders = new string[][] { strAuth };

    TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1[] WorkspaceRequest = MakeRequest<TogglWorkspaceTest.Class1[]>("https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces", myHeaders);
```

Thanks again to @Plutonix!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Json.NET, you can use the generic form of [DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can go for anonymous type to deserialize the json string.
Here is an example -

> var definition = new { Name = "" };
>
> string json1 = @"{'Name':'James'}"; var customer1 =
>   JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);
>
> Console.WriteLine(customer1.Name); // James
>
> string json2 = @"{'Name':'Mike'}"; var customer2 =
>   JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json2, definition);
>
> Console.WriteLine(customer2.Name);

Source for the above example is -
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

The following post is more detailed one - 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexghi/2008/12/22/using-anonymous-types-to-deserialize-json-data/